# How to prefix certain characters in a string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose the following,

```
const str = `
    hello!
    proceed - click button below.
`
```

I need to prefix certain characters with `\\`. In this case, I need the following result:

```
`
    hello\\!
    proceed \\- click button below\\.
`
```

Currently, I am doing this:

```js
const str = `
    hello!
    proceed - click button below.
`.replace(/!/gm, '\\!').replace(/-/gm, '\\-').replace(/\./gm, '\\.')

console.log(str);
```

Seems messy. Any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capture groups. Inside group `()` have the characters you'd like to replace `[!\-.]` and then in the replace reference the group `$1`. You also need to add extra `\\` to get 2 in the final output

```js
const str = `
    hello!
    proceed - click button below.
`.replace(/([!\-.])/gm, '\\\\$1')
console.log(str)
```

Comment: How can I get the expected result? This only adds one back slash before each character